# Error when loading YAML config files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, mongodb

I am configuring Rails with MongoDB, and find a strange problem when paring `config/mongo.yml` file.

`config/mongo.yml` is generated by executing `script/rails generate mongo_mapper:config`, and it looks like following:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: tc_web_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: tc_web_test
```

From the config file we can see the objects `development` and `test` should both have a `database` field. But when it is parsed and loaded in `config/initializers/mongo.db`,

```
config = YAML::load(File.read(Rails.root.join('config/mongo.yml')))
puts config.inspect
MongoMapper.setup(config, Rails.env)
```

the strange thing comes: the output of `puts config.inspect` is

```
{"defaults"=>{"host"=>"127.0.0.1", "port"=>27017}, "development"=>{"host"=>"127.0.0.1", "port"=>27017}, "test"=>{"host"=>"127.0.0.1", "port"=>27017}}
```

which does not contain `database` attribute. But when I execute the same statements in a plain ruby console, instead of using `rails console`, `mongo.yml` is parsed in a right way.

```
{"defaults"=>{"host"=>"127.0.0.1", "port"=>27017}, "development"=>{"host"=>"127.0.0.1", "port"=>27017, "database"=>"tc_web_development"}, "test"=>{"host"=>"127.0.0.1", "port"=>27017, "database"=>"tc_web_test"}}
```

I am wondering what may be the cause of this problem. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system, Ruby may have been compiled with `Psych` support, which replaces the older `Syck` parser. The issue you're seeing (which only involves using a "dry" yaml file with the defaults) has already been fixed in `Psych`, but is not yet in a released Ruby version.

For now, you can either force the YAML parser to use Syck instead of Psych by putting this at the end of your boot.rb (but beware -- a future version of Ruby will no longer include Syck):

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

Or you could just use a non-DRY YAML file (without the defaults) for the time being.