# how to access a YML Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I have the following yml

**/config/s3.yml**

```
common: &common
    access_key_id: asddasadsadsad
    secret_access_key: adsasddasdasdsa+qlSn+dadadada

development:
    <<: *common
    bucket: XX_dev

test:
    <<: *common
    bucket: XX_test

production:
    <<: *common
    bucket: XX_prod


  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => { :thumb => "70x70>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :bucket => "????How to get this from the YML based on the ENV???",
```

And I want to use this in paperclip, how can I access the bucket? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass a `:bucket` parameter, Paperclip will already know to use the `bucket:` key for the current environment from your `s3.yml` file.

Also note that if you manually compiled Ruby 1.9.2 via RVM, there is a chance that you are falling victim to a bug in the new Psych YAML engine. It doesn't like "DRY" yaml files (yet -- it's been filed as a bug and should be fixed in the next official release of Ruby). What happens is that each item that inherits from `common`, **only** contains those inherited items (your access key and secret id), and doesn't actually include the additional stuff you add (in your case, your bucket name).

Try making a traditional `yml` file instead without the `common` section (i.e. repeat the access key and secret id for each environment). More info: [Error when loading YAML config files in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538098/error-when-loading-yaml-config-files-in-rails/6538217#6538217)

**UPDATE**

The newest release of Ruby that came out today (1.9.2-p290) includes a fix for this issue.

Comment: Dylan, that's what I thought to, but after upgrading to RVM, if I don't specify a bucket I get the error: AWS::S3::CurrentBucketNotSpecified in RegistrationsController#create

No bucket name can be inferred from your current connection's address (`s3.amazonaws.com')

Comment: Using paperclip (2.3.15) ,,, aws-s3 (0.6.2) -- This all started happening after I installed RVM.

Comment: See my comment about yml files, since it coincides with a new ruby installation, I'm almost positive it's a yaml parsing issue.

Comment: Great! Make sure to accept answers that work for you, you'll have a better chance of getting responses to future questions the more you accept.

Answer (score 15):

Create a file in your initializers and put this inside:

```
raw_config = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(raw_config)
```

Then in your app, you'll access it's values this way:

```
APP_CONFIG[Rails.env]["bucket"]
```

Comment: +1 for technically answering the question of "how to access a yml value" :)

Comment: @Dylan Markow: ahah! well, wasn't worth your real added value on this topic but thanks ;)

Comment: Last thing I knew ```.load``` causes hanging file descriptors. Replace with ```.load_file``` and it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bit shorter:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "s3.yml"))
```